# (SOLVED) MS Server 2008: win10 client cannot login with the domain administrator

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, internal-dns, windows-10

I've got the problem that the workstation has wrong DNS settings in the network adapter.
Therefor, each attempt to login as domain admin results in the error: "there are currently no logon servers available".

I've tried to boot win10 in safe mode with and without networking, but still an administrator login is need, and it can't be validated.
The local administrator is being set to inactive, and can't be activated without the domain admin.

As network user, I do have all my network shares.
I've given this user admin rights on the server, but the user doesn't have the rights after login.

I can see the wrong IP addresses for the DNS in the registry for this user, but still not allowed to save new values for them.

I can connect to the server as admin, but have no clue on how to fix this.

So I'm running in circles here.

Any thoughts on solving this, without reinstalling the pc?

Comment: Has the domain Administrator logged into this computer previously? If so, you should be able to disconnect the machine from the network and log in as the domain Administrator with cached credentials.

Comment: Yes we have but it still gives the same message that the server is unreachable for verification.

Comment: Remotely connecting to the registry is not allowed either: "Make sure you have permission to administer this computer".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly no simple solution found.
Solved the problem with this instruction: https://4sysops.com/archives/offline-activate-the-built-in-administrator-on-windows-10-without-signing-in/

Re-activated the local administrator and removed the pc from the domain.
And added it back in.